# RequireJS - load lodash modules separately instead of whole library

Tags: javascript, requirejs, lodash

I am using `RequireJS` and I would like to load `lodash` modules that I need separately instead of loading the whole library.

From what I red, I should define lodash as a package in my config file:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : "./scripts",
    packages : [{ 
        name : "lodash",
        location : "../lib/lodash/lodash.min",
        main : "lodash"
    }]
});
```

Then in a module I am trying to load `lodash/Array/intersectionBy`

```
define(function(require) {
    var intersectionBy = require("lodash/Array/intersectionBy");
});
```

But I got the following error:

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found - 
>   http://localhost:8080/home/lib/lodash/lodash.min/Array/intersectionBy.js

---

#### Edit:

I downloaded lodash.min.js and lodash.core.min.js and put it directly in a lib folder :

```
project folder
 |_____lib
 |      |_____lodash
 |
 |_____scripts
        |_____config.js
```

Comment: How do you get lodash into your local filesystem? What specific package do you install, and how do you install it? (Edit your question with the answers.)

Comment: is 'lib' in the 'scripts' directory? You're munging the path, if so. The relative path in 'location' is likely the culprit. Also - Is there a reason you are using require.config.packages instead of require.config.paths?

Comment: No, I dont think its the problem. I have no problem to load lodash.min.js and use it as a whole

Comment: I'm not sure requireJs supports loading exported modules like that. I poked around a bit and couldn't find any confirmation of that, but the fact that it's trying to load `lodash.min/Array...` seems to support that.

Comment: Your notation is searching for the folder `lodash/Array/intersectionBy`. I've seen things like `lodash!array intersectionBy` (or maybe `lodash!array!intersectionBy`?). If that doesn't work, you're going to have to explicitly break out lodash into separate files for each module.

Comment: Made a mistake earlier. Try `lodash!Array/intersectionBy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**name** is a name of a package

**location** is a location of a package (not module)

**main** is a default file name of a module (default **main**)

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : "./scripts",
    packages : [{ 
        name : "lodash",
        location : "../lib/lodash/",
        main : "lodash.min"
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thats right, but I still have this error: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/Atlas_Defavorisation/lib/lodash/Array/union.js"

Comment: My god, I realize I was not using lodash AMD build